# Problema con validacion kotlin de 4 o mas variables para que no sean iguales

Tags: android, kotlin

1. Hola tengo una duda con respecto a la validacion de muchas variables que en este caso son solo 4, mi problema es que no se como validar mas variables (ej: 10) sin tener que escribir 45 veces las posibles igualdades. Aqui hay un ejemplo de 4 variables que hice de manera un poco arcaica. Mi pregunta es. ¿Existe alguna forma de comprobar si las variables son iguales sin tener que recurrir a esto (numeroJugador1 == numeroJugador2 ...etc)?

   ```
    while(numeroJugador1 == numeroJugador2 || numeroJugador2 == numeroJugador3 || numeroJugador1 == numeroJugador3 || numeroJugador1 == numeroJugador4 || numeroJugador3 == numeroJugador4 || numeroJugador2 == numeroJugador4){
                    numeroJugador1 = (0..3).random()
                    numeroJugador2 = (0..3).random()
                    numeroJugador3 = (0..3).random()
                    numeroJugador4 = (0..3).random()
                }//aleatorizacion de dos equipos distintos de 2 jugadores
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Mirando tu código deduzco que lo que quieres hacer es asignarle a cada equipo un número de manera aleatoria y validar que no hay dos equipos con el mismo número. Entonces, como ya te diste cuenta, de la manera en que lo estás haciendo se vuelve inviable porque conforme agregas una variable, el número de validaciones crece según la cantidad de variables ya existentes. Otra falencia es que conforme más y más variables hay, la probabilidad de que no se repita ningún número tiende a ser nula, por lo que prácticamente nunca saldría del ciclo.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el operador `shuffled` que a partir de una lista, un arreglo, un rango, etc. ordena de forma aleatoria los elementos y luego lo único que debes hacer es asignarle a cada equipo el número correspondiente según el índice en el que quedó. Algo así:

```
fun main() {
    val range: IntRange = 0..3
    val ids = range.shuffled()
    for (i in ids.indices) {
        println("ID del Equipo #${i + 1}: ${ids[i]}")
    }
}
```

Ejemplo del resultado de una ejecución:

```
ID del Equipo #1: 3
ID del Equipo #2: 0
ID del Equipo #3: 2
ID del Equipo #4: 1
```